# прописать метатэги через php условие

Tags: php, drupal, meta

Здравстуйте, уважаемые пользователи. Дело в том, что мне нужно прописать метатэги к определенным страницам в друпале, но есть доступ только к фтп, поэтому у меня такой вопрос. Можно как то в коде шаблона прописать через php условие: что то типо if current page = "наша страница", то её тайтл и дескрпшен равен тому то. Примерно как на рисунке
 [image: что то типо этого]

Comment: Конечно можно. Аналогично.

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать точную команду, ибо та которую прописал я, не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите все условия в функцию:

```
function md_title(){
    if(is_category() || is_tag()){single_cat_title();}
    elseif(is_month()){the_time('Архив за F, Y года');}
    elseif(is_day()){the_time('Архив за j F Y года');}
    elseif(is_year()){the_time('Архив за Y год');}
    md_paged();
}
```

А потом выведите результат функции:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php md_title()?>">
```

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример, как в этой ситуации прописать тайтл и дексрипшн, скажем для сайта vk.com

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен этот модуль:

https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag

В нем можно прописывать метатеги как в общем сайту, так в частности отдельным страницам или группам страниц

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую присмотреться к ответам @Crantisz и @Vadizar - их решение на много лучше и грамотнее.

Если по каким-то причинам оно вам не подходит, то вот простой код, который поможет сделать то, что вы хотите:

```
$data = array(
        'index.php' => '
                <title>Главная</title>
                <meta name="description" content="главная страница....">',
        'test.php' => '
                <title>Страница</title>
                <meta name="description" content="какая-то страница">'
    );

    ?>
    <html>
        <head>

        <?php print $data[basename(__FILE__)]; ?>

        </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
```